# Where might I find a "lines to pages" converter?

Tags: book-length

I'm looking for a **specifically *lines*** to pages converter. A Google search didn't really help. What's a formula or resource I could use?

Comment: Lines / Lines per Page = Pages

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand your question. What lines? What pages? What context? What are you talking about?

Comment: Both lines and pages are dependent upon the formatting of the eventual output. A given chuck of text may grow or shrink when the font and/or typeface is changed (without any change to the content). The number of lines per page will change depending upon whether the book (assuming that it is a book) is a hardback, softback, reduced-format paper back, or several formats for eBooks. An eBook may not even recognize pages. Add hyphenation, justification, paragraph indentation, and similar formatting conventions, and the answer (even given a specific format) becomes fuzzy at best.

Comment: How tall is your font?  How large is your page?  What spacing to you have between lines and / or paragraphs?

Answer (score 1):

You can't determine the number of lines per page until you first determine the number of words per line—and the online calculators I've seen convert from words to pages, not lines to pages.

Any reasonable calculator should at least take into consideration font face, font size, and line spacing in order to provide a general guideline.

From [my answer](https://writing.stackexchange.com/a/36104/30561) to [How many book pages would 891 words be?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/q/36103/30561)

> Here are some online "calculators" I found that will let you adjust the font face, size, and number of words in order to produce a page count estimate:
>
> [WordCounter](https://wordcounter.net/words-per-page)
> [Convert Words to Pages](http://www.wordstopages.com/)
> [Word Count to Page Count](https://essayscam.org/word-page-count-calculator/)
> [Words to Page Converter](https://writingpeak.co.uk/words-to-page-converter)

Note that the specifications for the book (border, format, and so on) can change these calculations even further.

You can estimate the number of pages given all of these variables, but if any of the variables change, the number of pages will also change.